# How to handle different Task exceptions with Wait() of parent and child.ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, exception, task-parallel-library

I have some hierarchy of parent/child tasks:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var t21 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                throw new Exception("Inner fault");
            }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        var t22 = t21.ContinueWith(ant =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner handler: " + ant.Exception.InnerException.Message);
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        throw new Exception("Outer fault");
    });

try
{
    t1.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    foreach (var e in ae.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        Console.WriteLine("Outer handler: " + e.Message);
}
```

As result, "Outer handler" handles exception that had been already handled by "Inner handler":

```
Inner handler: Inner fault
Outer handler: Outer fault
Outer handler: Inner fault
```

Is it possible to prevent handling of already handled exceptions in "Outer handle" ("Inner handler" in my example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you remove `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` on `t21`.

In that case you may want to add `t22.Wait()` in `t1` to reproduce the behavior of the [attached child task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx).